# How to find the coordinates of excel sheet using office apps development

Tags: javascript, excel, office-app

I am developing an excel office app. I need to update a cell using its coordinates. How to do this with **javascript**. for an example,

```
var x =1;
var y =2;

update_cell(1,2,'string');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same task. Apparently, there is no way in the current JavaScript API for Office 1.1.

A workaround, which worked in our scenario was to create a binding of the cell when:
- a user selects it or
- in the initial template we gave her

Check the Office.context.bindings object in the API help http://zoom.it/F2u0#full and try this as well:

```
Office.select('bindings#' + bindingId).setDataAsync(value, { coercionType: "matrix" });
```